# Does UIView's removeFromSuperView method remove the UIView from memory

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Does UIView's removeFromSuperView method remove the UIView from memory?  I just want to be sure that the view is no longer using any memory?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. Once `removeFromSuperView` method is called, that view is also released from memory.

If you want to confirm with Apple's documentation, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) is the link.

Comment: This answer should not be the "best answer" since it's not completely correct. It depends if the UIView has been retained some more. The second answer is better in explaining all details!

Answer (score 44):

`UIView` retains its subviews, so when you call `-removeFromSuperview` method then your view object is released.

So if everything else is ok with your memory management and your view is not retained by anything else then yes - your view should be deallocated and removed from memory.

Possible example when simply removing view from superview may not be sufficient to deallocate it can be view that has outlet connection and declared property for it with retain attribute - in that case it is retained by controller when it is being loaded from nib file and you may need to release that view for that case:

```
[iVarView removeFromSuperview];
self.iVarView = nil;
```

Comment: The big exception is if the view you remove is managed by a secondary view controller, then that view controller must also release the view before it can be removed from memory.

Comment: @Peylo, yes that what I meant in "ok with memory management", but it was not good phrase it seems